# java:how is it possible to see behind of a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, opacity, jviewport

how is it possible to see behind of a `JScrollPane`? I tried to do that via:

```
JScrollPane.setOpaqe(false);
```

but it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try both together:

```
jScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
jScrollPane.getViewPort().setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Plus jScrollPane.setOpaue(false) and make sure that the viewport's view is transparent as well +1